# How to sort data from a file into two different columns

Tags: c#, linq, xaml, io, wpfdatagrid

So I am making an Attendance App. There are two files that I will get the data.

First the excel file looks like this

[image: Schedule File]

Then this is the actual attendance logs

[image: Actual Attendance Logs]

For the attendance file 0 means login and 1 means logout

When I upload the attendance file, it looks like this
[image: DataGrid1]

So far, I have tried matching the two columns within a timespan but it gives me an error

[image: Error Message]

So at the moment this is what I have already done
[image: Current Table]

I am missing one more column that I need to calculate the metrics that should look like this
[image: Expected Output]

This is my current XAML code of my DataGrid

```
<ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
                    <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical" Margin="0,0,0,0">

                        <DataGrid
                            x:Name="dgvAttendance"
                            Margin="0,20"
                            CanUserSortColumns="True"
                            CanUserAddRows="False" SelectedIndex="0" AlternationCount="2" AutoGenerateColumns="True" SelectionMode="Single" EnableColumnVirtualization="True" IsReadOnly="True" ScrollViewer.CanContentScroll="False" CanUserReorderColumns="False" CanUserResizeColumns="False" HeadersVisibility="All" CanUserResizeRows="False" PreviewMouseWheel="DgvAttendance_PreviewMouseWheel" UseLayoutRounding="False" >
                        </DataGrid>

                        <Button
                            x:Name="btnExportExcel"
                            Style="{StaticResource MaterialDesignRaisedDarkButton}"
                            Width="110"
                            ToolTip="Resource name: MaterialDesignRaisedLightDarkButton" Margin="15,10" Content="Export File" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Click="BtnExportExcel_Click"  />
                    </StackPanel>
                    <!-- Stack for Datagrid Ends Here -->
                    </ScrollViewer>
```

And this is the code I am currently using to populate my DataGrid

```
public void Main()
        {

            actuals = NewActual(@"C:\Users\IT\Desktop\Sample\SampleActual.dat");
            emps = GetEmp();

            var final = (from t1 in actuals
                         join t2 in emps on t1.ID equals t2.ID
                         where t1.ID == t2.ID
                         orderby t2.ID
                         select new
                         {
                             t1.ID,
                             t2.In,
                             t1.ActualLog,
                             t2.Out
                         });

            dgvAttendance.ItemsSource = final.ToList();
        }
```

Any ideas or help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks

Edit : What I am trying to do is to sort the data from the attendance logs using the log status which is either 0 or 1, if zero then the log status of that should go to Actual In column but if 1 it should go to actual out column

Comment: Which line of code give the error? `So far, I have tried matching the two columns within a timespan` you need to share the code of that too...

Comment: [link](https://imgur.com/a/HYW3sh3) here when I try to acc actual log again to match the logout

Comment: Why you want to have `t1.ActualLog` twice?

Comment: Because I am supposed to match the schedule to their actual attendance logs and calculate their metrics using those 4 figures

Comment: `select new` create a dynamic object, and it can not have two properties with the same name. So you can not have `t1.ActualLog` twice there.. You need to have two different properties there as `select new{ID = t1.ID,In=t2.In,ActualLog=t1.ActualLog,Out=t2.Out,ActualLog1=t1.ActualLog})`

Comment: Is there any way that I won't have repeating values? Like as I shown on the attendance logs file there is a 0 or 1 which is Time In and Time Out, is there a way I could use an IF statement to seperate them like ActualLog is for Time in and ActualLog1 is for Time Out? Thanks for the Idea by the way

Comment: Which property of `t1` represents 0 or 1 ? it completely unclear from your question what you are trying to do here and what is your expectation

Comment: I have a property of t1 that is LogStatus, if Logstatus==0 it means TimeIn, and the data should go to actual in, column. if logstatus==1 it means TimeOut and the data should go to actualOut column

Comment: `var query = from x in items
                join y in items
                    on x.Id equals y.Id
                where x.LogStatus == 0 && y.LogStatus == 1
                select new
                {
                    Id = x.Id,
                    TimeIn = x.LogTime,
                    TimeOut = y.LogTime
                };`

Comment: @ChetanRanpariya Ill try this out real quick

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187474/discussion-between-newboooooo-and-chetan-ranpariya).